# How to set Mat to Mat with a mask? (opencv)

Tags: matlab, opencv

I want to set certain pixels in a Mat to be equal to those in another Mat, according to a mask.
similar to this matlab code:

```
A(mask==1) = B(mask==1)
```

How do I do it in OpenCV?

comment- using OpenCV 2.4.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`copyTo`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#void%20Mat%3a%3acopyTo%28OutputArray%20m%29%20const) function:

```
B.copyTo(A, mask)
```